# jQuery's mousemove does not fire on blank div in ie6

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-6

I have some divs with just a width, height, and border. I am using:

```
$(".the_divs").bind("mousemove",function(ms){
     do_stuff(this);
});
```

My divs do not have any background css set (so you can see what is behind them). However, ie6 only fires the mousemove event when the mouse is over the border of the div. So, if you quickly move the mouse into the div (past the border), it never gets fired.

If I set the background to a color this problem is fixed.
I tried the following with no luck:

```
background: none transparent;
```

I think I could put another div inside and set the width to 100% or something, but I'm looking for the easiest solution as this is part of a bigger project.

Thanks

Comment: need to mark this as a duplicate question of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299926/ie-mousemove-bug

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found a hack/fix. On my ie6 only css sheet, I set the background of these divs to a transparent gif. It seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid having a transparent GIF background by simply using an invalid image URL, for example:

```
background-image: url(#);
```

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like a css issue with ie 6. I would recommend trying

```
display:block
```

also, setting the width and height of the div is probably a good idea too. here's a great resource to understanding and fixing a lot of the weird shit that ie6 does:
http://satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html